# Numerical values of parametric differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I would like to get a list or a table of the numerical values  of function ch[s] for a specific s, lets say s1=-10^-4, taking into account the parameters m1, φ. It doesn't seem to work with what i have typed. Here is the code i use.
Thank you

```
q0 = 5.3;
ε0 = 2.2;
Γ = 5/3;
μ = 0.001;
ψ0 = 40;
l = μ/2;
Ω0 = 10;

ω0[s_] := (l R[s] μ)/((l^2 + R[s]^2)^2)
h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]*μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)]
U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)
sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 *Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
Dsonic[s_] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1) +
 h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3)
dΔ0[s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + 
Δ0[s]^Γ) ε0^2 (-2 R[s]^2 + (l^2 + R[s]^2) F[s]) Δ0[s]^(2 Γ)

 dF[s_] := 
 F[s]*Dsonic[s] + (F[s]^2 (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s]))/(4 π R[s]^2 sG[s]^2)*
 Dsonic[s]

ch[s_] := (R[s] - R0)^2 + (Δ0[s] - Δ00)^2 + (F[s] - F0)^2 - δc;


δc = 10^-4;

R0 = 0.10465641807783241`;

F0 = 1.9881644662604596`;

Δ00 = 16.5;

Rinit = R0 + δc*m1;
Δinit = Δ00 + δc*Sqrt[1 - 1^2]*Cos[\[Phi]];
Finit = F0 + δc*Sqrt[1 - m1^2]*Sin[\[Phi]];
m1min = 0.2;
m1max = 0.4;
mstep = 0.1;
\[Phi]min = 1.1 π;
\[Phi]max = 1.2 π;
\[Phi]step = 0.1 π;

 smax = -0.01;

 sol = ParametricNDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == dΔ0[s]*Dsonic[s], 
  R'[s] == Dsonic[s], F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, 
  R[0] == Rinit}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, smax}, {m1, \[Phi]}];

  ParametricPlot[
   Flatten[Table[{R[m1, \[Phi]][s], 
   Dsonic[s] /. {R[s] :> R[m1, \[Phi]][s], 
   Δ0[s] :> Δ0[m1, \[Phi]][s], F[s] :> F[m1, \[Phi]][s]}} /. 
sol, {m1, m1min, m1max, 
mstep}, {\[Phi], \[Phi]min, \[Phi]max, \[Phi]step}]], {s, 0, 
smax}, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Full, 
AxesLabel -> {"R", "γu0"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20], 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

Comment: The three equations in `ParametricNDSolve` have six dependent variables `{dF[s], Dsonic[s], d\[CapitalDelta]0[s], F[s], R[s], \[CapitalDelta]0[s]}` so the system is underdetermined. The definition of `ch[s]` should have a pattern on the LHS, i.e., `ch[s_]`. There are syntax problems that can be addressed once you provide additional equations or definitions for some of the dependent variables.

Comment: The system is not under determined. I have just tested it and i added Parametric Plot line so that you can see the results. If needed i can provide the script. I don't know how to get the values of the function ch[s] for a specific s. I corrected the ch[s_] as you suggested.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I might have misinterpret something, but why do  you say Dsonic[s] is undefined? It is defined just underneath sG[s] in line 13 ,14.  I just want to be able to print the numerical value of ch[s] for a specific s and for all the different values of m1,φ. Thank you for the help and sorry if i have misunderstood something.

Comment: I must have miscopied your code from the question.  Sorry.  In any case, your code produces what appears to be your desired curves.  What is the remaining issue?

Comment: How do i print a specific value of ch[s]. Lets say ch[-10^-5] for all the m1, φ i specify during integration